# Can access my website without going through the authentification page

Tags: php

I have a website and I want it to be accessible through an authentification page called login.html where is my form.
My authentification page works, but if I write the direct URL of my website in the address bar, like www.website.com/index.html, I can access my website without going through the authentification page.
So here is my code called 'login.php', to access my postgresql database where my logins and passwords are.

```html
<?php
 
// Parametre de  connection 
$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'base';
$user = 'postgres';
$pass = 'postgres';
$port = '5432';
 
$dns = 'pgsql:host='.$host .';port='.$port .';dbname='.$database;
 
try
{
 
  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['mdp'])) {
  extract($_POST);
 
  $bdd = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$user,$pass);
  $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 
  $sql = $bdd->query("SELECT pwd FROM nom_table WHERE login = '".$login."'");
 
  $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
  if ($result['pwd'] != $mdp) {
    echo '<body onLoad="alert(\'Mauvais mot de passe\')">';
    header ('location:login.html');
  }
  else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    echo 'Vous êtes connecté';
    header ('location:index.html');
  }
}
else {
    echo '<body onLoad="alert(\'Les variables du formulaire ne sont pas déclarées\')">';
    header ('location:login.html');
}
 
 
    }
catch(Exception $e)
{
        echo "Connection a la BDD impossible : ", $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
 
//header('Location:index.html');
?>
```

Then I've added this code at the beggining of my website code :

```html
<?
session_start();
 
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
  header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you running the session check on your index.html. If so you need to add it to a php page and include it, or make index.html -> index.php. Also in your login page I don't see you setting the variable $login.

Comment: @SteampunkForge, ok, I've changed my index.html to index.php but didn't change anything. How can I declare my variable login if it comes from my postgres table here ? I was thinking it would works just query it in my SQL

Comment: I tried an echo $login and it returns my login well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its a typo, but your page must have ".php" extension, and not ".html".